# In MYSQL, what is the equal keyword of ROWID (In oracle)

Tags: mysql

MySQL - In a table i would like to select last 2 rows based on their insertion order. Since i don't have any unique combination columns in the table. Sample table is like below,

| Patch | Description | Environment |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1.2 | 1st Patch | Prod |
| 1.3 | 2st Patch | Prod |
| 2.1 | 1st Patch | DEV |
| 2.2 | 2st Patch | DEV |

In Oracle, we can achieve this by using ROWID. Do we have any similar/approach in MYSQL. Please guide.

Comment: MySQL (more precisely - InnoDB) implements inner row number, but it is not accessible. What is **precise** version of your MySQL server?

Answer (score 1):

MySQL 8.0 implements the window function `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(...)`. This is more flexible than Oracle's ROWNUM pseudocolumn, and it's standard SQL. There are other window functions too.

See: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions.html